# Why it has got two different result with the same "inputs"

Tags: python, algorithm, object

I don't understand why it has two difference result. Please help me, to explain these results.

This is my codesorce:

```
# coding: iso-8859-2

class Satelite:
    def __init__(self, name, mass=100, speed=0):
        self.name, self.mass, self.speed= name, mass, speed

    def lokes(self, power, time):
        self.speed=self.speed+ power*time/ self.mass

    def energy(self):
        return self.mass* self.speed**2/2

    def out_speed(self):
        print "%s Satelites's speed = %s m/s" %(self.name, self.speed)

# Tesztprogram:

s1=Muhold('Zoe', mass=250, speed=10)

s1.lokes(500,15)
s1.out_speed()
print s1.energy()

s1.lokes(500,15)
s1.out_speed()
print s1.energy()
```

These are the results:

```
Zoe Satelite speed= 40 m/s
200000
Zoe Satelite speed= 70 m/s
612500
```

Comment: Why not? You're modifying `self.speed` in `lokes`.

Comment: Hopefully, you are trying to learn Python, and not developing actual satellite software :)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn Python, but over 1-2 year, maybe I will developing satellite software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're modifying a state variable in the middle.

```
def lokes(self, power, time):
    # this reassigns speed, so next time the function is called, 
    # it will be higher.
    self.speed=self.speed+ power*time/ self.mass
```

Since `speed` is changed, and the `energy` method depends on `speed`, then the output of `energy` should change every time you call lokes with values other than `0`.

Comment: Yes, really. I overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `lokes()` method mutates the object, meaning that you *don't* have the same input each time.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting different results because you aren't resetting `self.speed` between calls to `s1.lokes(500,15)`

```
def lokes(self, power, time):
    self.speed=self.speed+ power*time/ self.mass
```

Since the execution of `lokes` both modifies and uses `self.speed` it will influence later calls unless you manually set `self.speed` or reset the satellite.